# Does Bluetooth 4.0 penetrate concretes?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy, 802.11

I am working on an application where I want to make wireless communication between two embedded devices. The core problem here is that I want to put one of these devices in a room that's totally built as concrete, even its door will be concrete.

Does Bluetooth 4.0 support that?
If not, Is there any solution?

Thanks

Comment: Does the concrete contain rebar? How thick is the concrete - clearly if it was 4 feet thick compared to say 1 inch, that would make a massive difference.

Comment: yes, it contains

Comment: the door thick is about 15 cm max

Comment: I think the door will be less than 10 cm anyway

Comment: As with many things, "it depends". In this case, it depends on how much the concrete functions as a dielectric vs. a conductor. If the concrete is moist or has a lot of metal embedded in it, there will be more attenuation of radio signals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need:

- The steel framework design of the walls,
- How thick are the steel bars,
- How separated are bars,
- Which kind of concrete is used in the wall,
- The thickness of the wall.

Besides, you will require to know the following:

- The distance from both devices to the wall,
- The bandwidth required to be transmitted.

With that, you can make a very simplified FEM simulation in order to calculate the signal attenuation and only then you will be able to know if the Bluetooth is able to accept the level of attenuation you are getting.

Comment: actually, the main problem I am facing here is that I don't have a reference for the wall, there's a lot of manufacturers who make it in different ways, but the thing that I am sure about, is that the thickness of the wall door will not exceed 2 inches, and it may be in concrete or steel. Does it make sense for you ? will it work, or I have to test it myself on different cases ?

Comment: No, you are saying me you dont know the material. Are you clear that EM do not cross steel?. You at least should have clarified which are the choices

Comment: A 2 in concrete wall perhaps is too much attenuation for a weak sensor, by the way..... Besides, do you have the data bandwidth (bits|bytes per second)? That is another requirement

Comment: Why not just test it?  Grab your phone and a bluetooth headset and see what happens! :)

Comment: If he has the wall in there, that is the simplest way....

Comment: Thank you for your clarification, just one more question, how distance from the wall will affect the communication? you mean when distance increased the signal will be weakened, and will not be able to penetrate the wall ?

Comment: I can also say, that one of the devices, will be sticked on the wall itself.

Comment: Yeah sure, just any wave diffraction while changing the media impedance

Comment: The receiver should be sticker... The sender do not care.... too much